# What is the 14 pin IC that is associated with an ATMEL 312 24C02N IC?

Tags: digital-logic

Does anyone know what the 14 pin IC in this picture is? This circuit drives an RGB LED strip with 24 LEDs. The 14 pin IC does not have anything printed on the case. I understand that not having the part number printed on the case makes it difficult to know what specific IC is used in this circuit, for this very reason, I am asking electronic engineers for help. Thank you for taking the time to help me with my question.   [image: RGB Driver circuit]

Comment: 24C02N is an EEPROM. So *anything* that can read from it is "associated" with it.

Comment: Are there any markings on the PCB? It might hold clues for the ID of this chip.

Comment: If you have some IPA (isopropyl alcohol), put a drop on top of the IC and wait for it to evaporate. Once it evaporates the markings can suddenly become very legible.

Comment: ... I count 14 pins.

Comment: I didn't bother to count the pins. Thanks for the correction. I will apply isopropyl alcohol and try to make the print visible.

Comment: Is it possible that an NCP5623 is the correct IC that is used with an ATMEL 24C02N?

Comment: *Any* IC can be used with an EEPROM. There is no "correct IC" to be used with it.

Comment: Your question about the "correct" IC doesn't make much sense - it's like asking which car is the correct one for driving down the road. As long as it has the correct interface (two or more wheels, brake lights, turn signals, etc), then it can utilize the road. As long as an IC has the correct interface (2-wire/I2C), then it can utilize the EEPROM. The whole point of standardized interfaces, like 2-wire, is that the circuit designer can choose the device that best suites his/her needs without worrying about how they'll communicate - as long as they both support the interface, they can talk.

Comment: @MetalTechKreator However, to directly answer your earlier question in the comments, there *are* indeed wrong ICs to use with it. The unidentified IC is not a NCP5623. An RBG driver wouldn't directly read from the EEPROM itself. They are both passive devices that just respond to commands, so there needs to some kind of controller in between. Also, look at the pinouts in the datasheets - if the unidentified IC were the NCP5623, then the EEPROM's SDA/SCL pins would be connected to its GND and LED1 output.

Answer (score 2):

Since this device drives LEDs *and* is connected to an EEPROM (the [ATMEL 312 24C02N](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc0180.pdf)), it is likely some kind of microcontroller.

There aren't very many types of components that would make sense being connected to both a memory device and a set of LEDs. If it were only connected to the EEPROM, it could be something like a protocol bridge to allow a microcontroller without a 2-wire serial controller to interface with the EEPROM (SPI -> 2-wire, for example). If it were only connected to the LEDs, it could be an LED driver, or a simple multiplexer. But some type of controller is really the only thing that makes sense for connecting to both of them. There is a very slim (but non-zero) chance that it is an FPGA or ASIC, but a 14-pin DIP package for these is pretty unlikely, so the most likely candidate is a small microcontroller like a PIC or AVR.

Unfortunately it's nearly impossible to know exactly what kind without finding some kind of identifier printed on the board or documentation for the board (layout, schematic, BOM, etc).

Comment: I do not agree that it's unlikely to be an ASIC. If this is a tiny little device of which thousands upon thousands are made, it's at least much more likely 8051 or OTP, and not unlikely a purpose made ASIC. There is no print, it's not scraped off.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the picture above, the 14 pin IC is connected to Atmel EEPROM for the pins 5 & 6 which are I2C signals.

[image]

As they are connected to I2C and EEPROM does have I2C controller so the 14 pin IC is most probably a Micro controller having I2C controller. and the controller may have high drive pin to drive LEDs directly. It may be either PIC or AVR

Comment: Or TI or Freescale or any other weird brand 8051, or OTP, or ASIC, or....