# What is this 14 pin IC that is associated with an ATMEL 312 24C02N IC?

Tags: microcontroller, identification, reverse-engineering

so Basically This is a duplicate question Posted 5 years ago [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/233630/what-is-the-14-pin-ic-that-is-associated-with-an-atmel-312-24c02n-ic)
which is closed with unclear answer.
but here i have found something.

---

this is actually a RGB Controller module, it has,

**1** *12v input*

**2** *12v-G-R-B connector(rgb connector)*

**3** *Three Buttons(change the way Light Glow)*
[image]

It has a ATMEL 312 24C02N which a Serial EEPROM and connected to this 14pin ic, works with PWM to dim lights,
and by desoldering the ic i found out some name like **EH531** or something you can clearly see in the image. and also i got the pinout!

[image: this]
and
**PINOUT**

- 1 out1
- 2 -
- 3 -
- 4 vcc
- 5 SCL
- 6 SDA
- 7 -
- 8  In 1
- 9  In 2
- 10 In3
- 11 GND
- 12 -
- 13 Out2
- 14 Out3

In = from buttons,
Out = which goes to Transistor which controls the Led,
SCL = Serial Clock,
SDA = Serial Data

Datasheet of [ATMEL 312 24C02N](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/doc0180.pdf)

**What would be the 14 pin ic, i have googled enough and didnt found a single clue. Thank you**

Comment: As previously pointed out by your linked thread, the mystery chip is likely a microcontroller **of some sort**.  Simply replacing it would do no good, as you would still need to program it to tell it what to do.  So, unless you can scavenge this part off another identical unit, you are out of luck.

Comment: then should i also flash the eeprom right? i killed it too:)

Comment: Sounds like there's nothing left to save (unless you indeed do have spare chips, and the programmer and firmware available to you).  In all honesty, If I were troubleshooting this device, I would guess that the most likely bits to fail would be the components driving the outputs, not the uC or EEprom.  Without a schematic, it's only a wild guess.

Comment: i wildly shorted the vcc to one of the signal pin which is a i2c connection now both are heating like they are atomic bomb 60c to 80c may be